# Reading scale value based on mouse position with d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have created an x axis with some rectangle above. I would like to be able to read the value related to the mouse's x position. But the read values are not in agreement with the values from my x axis - usually they have some offset, different for different x axis extent. What am I missing?

```
export const AxisBottom = ({xScale, innerHeight, innerWidth, tickFormat}) => {

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
        let x = e.pageX;
        let year = xScale.invert(x);
        console.log(year);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <rect width={innerWidth} height={innerHeight} fill="white" opacity={0}
                  onMouseMove={(e) => handleMouseMove(e)}/>
            {
                xScale.ticks()
                    .filter(tickValue => Number.isInteger(tickValue))
                    .map((tickValue, i) => (
                        <g className="tick" key={i} transform={`translate(${xScale(tickValue)},0)`}>
                            <line y2={innerHeight} strokeDasharray="5,5"/>
                            {tickFormat &&
                                <text style={{textAnchor: 'middle'}} dy="1.2em" y={innerHeight + 3}>
                                    {tickFormat(tickValue)}
                                </text>
                            }
                        </g>
                    ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

`xScale` is defined in a parent component as:

```
const xScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain(extent(filteredData, d => d.year))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice();
```

Comment: `svg.on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var mouseX = d3.pointer(event)[0]; // get the x-coordinate of mouse relative to the SVG
    var index = Math.round(xScale.invert(mouseX)); // convert mouse x-coordinate to index of your data
    var value = data[index]; // get the value corresponding to the index
    console.log("Mouse X: " + mouseX + ", Value: " + value);
  });` Kindly use this

Comment: It works! It means that my problem was using pageX (and thus getting the coordinates corresponding to page) rather than d3.pointer (getting the coordinates corresponding to the svg element). Thank you!